# Repeated URL post parameters issue

Tags: php, url, magento-1.9

Hi can anyone help why URL string parameters post again and again?

```
HTTP://127.0.0.1/ab/1936.html?cart=yes?cart=yes
```

i m using this parameter to open mini cart when we added product into cart in magneto 1.9

Please help me how to protect this?
i am using this code-

```html
<?php
if ($_GET['cart']=='yes') {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          jQuery('.minicart_open').show();
    </script>";
}
?>
```

cartController.php

```
protected function _goBack()
{
    $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
   // print_r($returnUrl);exit;
    if ($returnUrl) {

        if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
            throw new Mage_Exception('External urls redirect to "' . $returnUrl . '" denied!');
        }

        $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    } elseif (!Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart')
        && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')
        && $backUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl()
    ) {
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl.'?cart=yes');
    } else {
        if (
            (strtolower($this->getRequest()->getActionName()) == 'add')
            && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')
        ) {
            $this->_getSession()->setContinueShoppingUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: What code you are using to append the ?cart=yes ? In which file you have placed that ?

Comment: i placed that code into cartController.php.. $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl.'?cart=yes');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer

> Just replace below line

```
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl.'?cart=yes');
```

To

```
$url = $backUrl; 
        // Search substring  
            if (strpos($url, $key) == false) { 
                 $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl.'?cart=yes');
            } 
            else { 
                 $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
            } 
            //exit;
```

its working for me...Hope its helpful for you...